# How to trigger a hidden UIButton's event in the action of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIButton`, which is placed over a `UINavigationBar's rightBarButtonItem`. The `UIButton` is hidden. So in the view only the `UINavigationBar's rightBarButtonItem` is visible. On the click of the `rightbarbuttonitem`, I want to trigger the action of the hidden `UIButton`. Is it possible. If so, how?

Edit: Is there any way to do this without using selectors. Is there a way like where I can just trigger the UIButton action on the click of the UIBarButtonItem, like action:UIButton.action

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code to trigger the action for UIBarButtonItem.  But you have tu use selector in this!!!

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad
    {
       // change the back button and add an event handler
       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pages"
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(handleBack:)];
    }

    - (void) handleBack:(id)sender
    {
        // do your custom handler code here

        // make sure you do this!
       // trigger an hidden button
[itsHiddenButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
```

. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The method called when rightBarButtonItem is touched can be called when UIButton is touched.

```
-(IBAction)rightBarButtonTrigger:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"rightBarButtonTrigger");
    [self uiButtonTrigger:sender];
}

-(IBAction)uiButtonTrigger:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"uiButtonTrigger");
}
```

Comment: I am creating the UIButton programmatically

Comment: You can use the same code in that case. Do you have a certain reason for not wanting to use selectors? UIButton inherits actions from UIControl. You can set an action when you create the UIButton or use UIControl's addTarget:action:forControlEvents: method and action takes a selector.

Comment: Is there a way, where I can set the UIBarButtonItem action as nil and instead trigger UIButton action programmatically.

Comment: If UIBarButtonItem's action is nil then it's nil. It won't do anything. You can set it to the same selector as your UIButton if you want. I separated the action for the two buttons in case there was something different you wanted to do with one button.

Comment: The problem is that my UIBarButtonItem gets released somewhere which I cant identify. So I would like to trigger the UIButton action in that case. Don't want to call UIButton's selector in UIBarButtonItem's action. Just need to call UIButton action.

Comment: Create a new question pertaining to that issue with sample code. You should never have to resort to this kind of workaround because of a memory management issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a common method for your both buttons `rightBarButtonItem` and `UIButton`. So they will fire the same method on its click event.